# How to get object values initialized in one activity into the other(Xamarin.Android)?

Tags: c#, android

I have the following C# namespace:

[C# namespace](https://pastebin.com/iSJTbzxe)

I get its values in MainActivity like that:

```
Settings settings;
settings = (Settings)deserializer.Deserialize(textReader);
```

Now I want its values to be accessible troughout all Activities in the application. I've tried make Settings class inherit from Application, implement Serializable or Parseable but it did't worked ,the last two don't even exist. Maybe bacause these are aproches in Java and for Xamarin.Android there are too little information. I've tried also making all properties static and referencing them in other activities but it did't work.Someone said that by that aproach the memory get full and the program runs slower so I'm not interested in it too much.

Comment: You can give each class in which you want to use `settings` a constructor that takes `Settings`, then pass `settings` in wherever you need it.

Comment: Can you give a little more detail? And I little more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give each class in which you want to use `settings` a constructor that takes an instance of `Settings`, then pass `settings` in when constructing new instances.

```
public class Activity1
{
    public Settings Config { get; private set; }

    public Activity1(Settings settings)
    {
        Config = settings;
    }       
}
```

Then, to use:

```
Settings settings;
settings = (Settings)deserializer.Deserialize(textReader);
var myActivity = new Activity1(settings);
var printer = myActivity.Config.Sections.Printing.Printer;
```

Comment: And if I want to go from MainActivity to Activity1 (when button clicked for example) , do I start the activity startActivity(myActivity) and Activity1 will contain settings data?

Comment: Let's take a step back here. Anytime I find myself passing an object into a method, I wonder, "Should the object be taking care of this itself"? So, instead of `startActivity(myActivity)`, maybe think about `myActivity.Start()`. That being said, in the example I posted the settings are encapsulated in `myActivity`. Wherever `myActivity` goes you can access them via `myActivity.Config`.